# Side effects, sequence points and undefined behaviour

Tags: c

I read in a book the following statement:

```
n = ((i++) > (j)?(i++):(j));
```

The book claims that presuming i >j, n has an unexpected value and i is incremented twice.
I don't understand why n has an expected value after this statement.

I read many examples about undefined behavior, so here's *my* theory (not the book's explanation, since there isn't) and tell me whether I'm right:

> first, (i++) > (j) is evaluated, and i may or may not be incremented
>   yet.
> Presuming i > n, (i++) should be evaluated. **We don't know
>   whether i has been incremented yet or not**, so that's why this entire
>   statement is undefined. we're not sure whether i or i+1 will be returned.

Now here's the problem presuming my theory is right - **Why don't we know
 whether i has been incremented yet or not** ? If this line of code were to be written as an if statement, I'm pretty sure i will have to be incremented before. So why is the compound if different?
Thank you.

Comment: You answered your question already in the title. Read about sequence points.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley: Thanks, CV withdrawn.

Comment: "So why is the compound if different?" Is it? http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.15p4

Comment: #offtopic: I think I have found one of the sources of the evil while looking up the relevant info: http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/pre-post-increment-same-expression/ (Disclaimer: DO NOT FOLLOW THIS GUIDE!)

Comment: @EugeneSh.and they have another one at http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/increment-operator-inside-printf/

Comment: Oh my... This site should be reported to the FBI :)

Comment: @EugeneSh.: This is one example of *thousands*.  It's all over the damned place, and no matter how many times you point it out, people still insist it's well-defined behavior; after all, it produces a result on *their* machine.

Comment: The unnamed book in this question is a rare example of the opposite of the usual problem. It wants to make you afraid of undefined behavior in an expression that's actually well-defined.

Comment: Funny pitfall after all, as I'd slap anyone trying to get code like this into production ;)

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley the book is C Programming, A Modern Approach 2nd Edition, p.323 and it's really been a great learning book even including that pitfall :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `?:` operator introduces a sequence point, so there's no undefined behavior here.

`(i++) > (j)` is evaluated *and the side effect of `i++` is applied*.  If the result of `(i++) > (j)` is true, then `(i++)` is evaluated again, otherwise `(j)` is evaluated again.

`i++` evalutes to the value of `i` *before* the increment.  So, assuming `i > j`, then after evaluating

```
n = i++ > j ? i++ : j;
```

the following should be true:

```
n = iorig + 1
i = iorig + 2
```

**Edit**

[Chapter and verse](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> **6.5.15 Conditional operator**
> ...
> 4 The first operand is evaluated; **there is a sequence point between its evaluation and the
> evaluation of the second or third operand** (whichever is evaluated). The second operand
> is evaluated only if the first compares unequal to 0; the third operand is evaluated only if
> the first compares equal to 0; the result is the value of the second or third operand
> (whichever is evaluated), converted to the type described below.<sup>110)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>110) A conditional expression does not yield an lvalue.</sup>

Comment: @JeffY: 6.5.15/4: "The first operand is evaluated; *there is a sequence point between its evaluation and the
evaluation of the second or third operand* (whichever is evaluated). "

Comment: Correct. Original deleted to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @JohnBode Wow, I think you've all just proved the book wrong (C Programming, a Modern Approach 2nd Edition, p.323 if you're curious). Perhaps this sequence point after 1st operand is new to the C99 or something, and this book covers the old C89 as well. Anyway, Thank you so much!

Comment: @NoamSolovechick: Don't think it's new with C99; I'm pretty sure it was true of C89 as well.  All books have mistakes, even good ones.  My go-to reference has been Harbison & Steele since the mid-80s, but even they screw up occasionally.  I've heard good things in general about King, so I doubt it's a bad book overall.

Comment: @JohnBode It is indeed a great book :) Again, thank you for clearing this out for me, you're awesome :)